# IGCSE to apply for Australian visa

Tags: visas, australia

Can I use my I IGCSE to apply for my work and holiday Australian visa?
Or should I take a TOEFL or IELTS?

Comment: What country are you from? This determines the 'Work and Holiday' visa requirements... that said, I imagine if an English test is required it'll be standard across the board...

Comment: Also, I think IGCSE is International GCSE (GCSE being the U.K. general set of qualifications achieved in your 3rd or 4th year of secondary education).

Comment: @MarkMayo no, TOEFL "is a test of an individual's ability to use and understand English in an academic setting" while TEFL "refers to teaching English to students whose first language is not English". IELTS is similar to TOEFL

Comment: TOEFL = "Test of English as a Foreign Language" usually required of foreign students applying to US universities.  Not sure what the rest of the alphabet soup means.

Comment: IELTS is a comparable English-as-a-foreign-language test. IGCSE is the international version of a U.K high school qualification. I used to teach the former, for my sins.

Comment: Based on what I can see IGCSE is a colledge qualification exams in multiple subjects.  So if part of that program you have passed an equivalent you might check with Australian Consulate if they will accept it.  If not you will need to take one of the tests mentioned.

Comment: It is not college qualification level. It is for 14-16 year olds, and each subject has its own IGCSE. See http://www.cie.org.uk/qualifications/academic/middlesec/igcse/overview

Comment: @Karlson IGCSEs are the international equivalent of the UK GCSE program sat many 16 yr olds who follow British curriculum outside the UK. The main difference between them & standard GCSEs is that they contain no coursework element (as such are becoming increasing popular with schools within the UK also). People who then continue there education post 16, then may progress to A levels in preparation for university entrance (alternatives to A levels include Pre U & International Baccalaureate (IB).

Answer (score 4):

One of the following is required (from the [Work and Holiday visa page of Australian immigration](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/working-holiday/462/)). The criteria in bold is likely where the IGCSE fits in.

> Achieved an IELTS average band score of at least 4.5 based on the four test components of speaking, reading, writing and listening in a test conducted no more than two years before lodging the visa application. For visa purposes you only need to sit the General Training Module.
>
> Achieved a TOEFL score of 133 on a computer based test, or 450 on a paper based test or 45-46 on an internet-based test, no more than two years before lodging the visa application.
>
> Passed the Occupational English Test no more than two years before lodging the visa application.
>
> Completed all years of primary education and at least three years of secondary education at an educational institution in which all instruction was in English.
>
> **Completed at least five years of secondary education (high school) at an educational institution in which all instruction was in English.**
>
> Completed a post-secondary qualification that required at least two years of full-time study or training, in which all tuition was in English.
>
> Successfully completed, in Australia, at least one year of full-time study or equivalent part-time study towards a degree, higher degree, diploma or associate diploma at an institution or institutions where all the instruction was in English.

However, I assume that passing the IGCSE isn't enough - at least 5 years of your secondary / high school education, in all subjects, must have been in English.

There are also additional education requirements that must be met based on your home country. You can find these from the page above by selecting your country.

Comment: You need qualifications to get a working holiday visa to my country??? I thought you just had to be from one of certain countries and be below the cutoff age. I'm a bit shocked. Or is this something different?

Comment: There are 'Working Holiday' visas, and 'Work and Holiday' visas. Looks like 'Work and Holiday' needs at least 'diploma level' qualifications, whilst 'Working Holiday' does not. Which you can apply for depends on your country. See http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/working-holiday/visa-options.htm.

Comment: This, of course, in addition to age requirements etc.

Answer (score 0):

This what is accepted (one being something from Cambridge):
https://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/aelt

However, the visa applications are never decided based on one criteria. If your country has low chance of getting visa you better have everything right. It is also likely they will require you to do the tests if they dont like your English certificate. However, I would suggest not taking the risk and just do the test.